# DB2 trigger, after insert delete

Tags: sql, db2

I'm attempting to write a trigger to delete from current table after a record has been inserted into the history table. I'm unsure of the syntax for the delete(triggered sql action) statement. Goes something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER A.DELETE_AFTER_INSERT NO CASCADE AFTER INSERT ONT A.LOAN_HIST LH
REFERENCING NEW AS NEWROW FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
DELETE * FROM A.LOAN L
--unsure about upcoming lines--
WHERE A.LOAN.LOAN_ID=NEWROW.LOAN_ID;
END
```

Essentially I'm not sure how to reference my where clauses. In the manual it seems like I need to when a when, which I don't see how to implement here. I'm also not sure if I can use table aliases here such as 'L' and 'LH'.

I can't just test it out because I don't have privilege to create triggers.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Would you like someone to check the manual and tell you where your syntax is off?

Comment: You can install a DB2 Express-C and test on your own machine.

Answer (score 0):

As AngocA notes, you should really just install db2 luw and play around with it.

But if it helps, here is the boilerplate I've used before:

```
 CREATE OR replace TRIGGER "trigger_name" AFTER 
 insert or delete or update ON TABLE_NAME REFERENCING NEW AS newrow OLD AS oldrow 
 FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL 
BEGIN 
    declare ...
    IF INSERTING THEN 
       ...
    ELSEIF DELETING THEN 
       ...
    ELSEIF UPDATING THEN 
       ...
    END IF; 
END
```